# Send mail using yahoo smtp in php with html formatted text

Tags: php, html, email

I am trying to send mail from PHP using my yahoo credentials.

```
$Mbody=$Mbody."<body>";
$Mbody=$Mbody."<table border=0>";
$Mbody=$Mbody."<tr>";
$Mbody=$Mbody."<td>Hi,</td>";
$Mbody=$Mbody."</tr>";
$Mbody=$Mbody."<tr>";
$Mbody=$Mbody."<td>New Mail for testing.</td>";
$Mbody=$Mbody."</tr>";
$Mbody=$Mbody."<tr>";
$Mbody=$Mbody."<td><a href=http://www.google.com >Verify Account</a></td>";
$Mbody=$Mbody."</tr>";
$Mbody=$Mbody."</table>";
$Mbody=$Mbody."</body>";
$Mbody=$Mbody."</html>";

$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; // enable SMTP authentication
$mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl"; 
$mail->Host = "plus.smtp.mail.yahoo.com";
$mail->Port = 465; // set the SMTP port
$mail->Username = "********";   
$mail->Password = "********"; 
$mail->From = "********";
$mail->FromName = "my Name";
$mail->AddAddress('********');
$mail->Subject = "Subject";
$mail->Body = $Mbody;
```

When I execute the code, it does send mail to desired recipient, but the body shows all HTML tag in the received mail. What is missing in above code.

Comment: Use  $mail->IsHTML(true); // send as HTML

Comment: Yes it does worked. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This

```
$mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML
$mail->Subject = 'Subject';
$mail->MsgHTML($Mbody);
$mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';
```

Answer (score 1):

Please use content-type as HTML

```
$mail->IsHTML(true); // send as HTML
```